# How do I mass delete users from Joomla? My website has been attacked by spambots and I have over 40,000 registered users but only 1 active user.

Tags: mysql, joomla, captcha

1. One of my Joomla sites has 1 active user but over 40,000 registered (spambot created) users! Going through the Joomla user interface and deleting these spam users 100 at a time will take ages, so I'm trying to find a way to mass delete through phpMyAdmin. I think I need to delete users from more than 1 table (the _users and _user_usergroup_map) so if anyone can help, please include the MySql queries needed to delete from both tables.
2. If I'm the only person setting up users on this site, how can I stop bots or others requesting a registration? Do I need to use Spambotcheck  (the Joomla component) or is there another way?
3. If I want others to self-register on a different site, what's the best way to use Captcha to do this? Do I need a separate plugin/component or does Joomla allow this?

Answer (score 2):

About question 1 :

Assuming that your active user id is 62.

```sql
# replace the 62 with your active used id
DELETE FROM #__users WHERE id > 62;

# replace the 62 with your active used id
DELETE FROM #__user_usergroup_map WHERE user_id > 62;
```

For the other 2 question is better you ask on https://joomla.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and managed to clean out a bunch of tables. Now Joomla only shows that there's 1 user which is great.

Unfortunately, when I look at the database as a whole, the tables I cleaned out are still massive, in the 10's of megabytes... I read somewhere that I need to optimise these tables to clean out the unused rows somehow. How do I do this?

Comment: from phpmyadmin click on the table you want to optimise > operations > in there at the bottom of the page you'll see Optimize table. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM `upd_user_usergroup_map`
WHERE user_id IN ( SELECT id FROM `upd_users` WHERE lastvisitDate="0000-00-00 00:00:00" )

DELETE FROM `upd_users` WHERE lastvisitDate="0000-00-00 00:00:00"
```